# Connection refused when trying to SSH into Virtualbox on Mac

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, opensuse

I'm trying to setup a Vagrantbox from scratch and I'm running into some issues. I've created a Virtual Box with openSUSE installed on it, and when I try to SSH into the VB I get this error: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.1 port 22: Connection refused`.

My port forwarding settings for the VB is: `Name: SSH, Protocol: TCP, Host IP: blank, Host Port: 2222, Guest IP: blank, Guest Port: 22`.

I get this when I run `ifconfig -a`: `vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.50.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.50.255`

Like I said, I'm very new to this so I've probably missed something trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> > ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.1 port 22: Connection refused

You're using the wrong port number.  Use `ssh -p 2222 user@host`

Host port is 2222 and guest port is 22.
Inside the VM, the port number is 22. But outside the VM, it's 2222.

Comment: A good reference for this is [Connecting To A Vagrant Box Without The 'vagrant ssh' Command](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/connecting-vagrant-box-without-vagrant-ssh-command)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I run your suggested command I get this message: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
`.

Comment: The vagrant host might be configured to only use keypair authentication.

Comment: How do I check that? @dop

Comment: It would likely be specified in either the Box file used to stage the deployment or the `Vagrantfile` used to provision it.